# O-QPSK constellation interpretation - GNU Radio

Tags: filters, qpsk, gnuradio

I am currently trying to recover the I&Q of a O-QPSK signal generate from the standard XBEE arduino module using a B200. I can get somehow get a "look-like" of a constellation. Here an screenshoot:
[image: OQPSK - constellation]

I highlight the zone where there is a symbol recover. When I run the acquisition I can see symbol at the places. Here we just see one because there is a limited number of points displayed. However what is the rest? I got a SPS (sample per symbol) of 2. A part of the rest is certainly the transistion, but I am quite sure there is phase noise also. How can I attenuate those points. My flowgraph is just a UHD source feed into the polyphase clock source which is sent to a costa loop and after that there is my QT constellation sink.

[EDIT]
A other picture with less points on it:
[image]

Comment: could you add a picture of your actual flow graph, too? What does the constellation look like before the PFB clock sync?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I checked the direct input, it seem that my USRP's gain was too high because there was saturation on that constellation. I will investigate furthermore. I am starting to have a decent signal.

Comment: that's great to hear! I think it would be cool if you could update your question over the next few days :) I'm looking forward to hearing how well the PFB clock sync works on O-PSK

Comment: @MarcusMüller You seem to use GNU-Radio, or to have knownledge about the API. Could you tell me the meaning of sample per symbol in the case of the PFB clock sync. Tutorial on PSK say that the sps is use to match the hardware sampling rate to the symbol/rate, but I don't get the meaning of that because the tutorial is limited to a simulation.

Comment: It means exactly that: How long, in samples, is a single symbol?

Comment: @MarcusMüller So if my signal bandwidth is 2 Mhz and I sample at 4Mhz, sps will be 2? But if I sample at 6 Mhz, the sps will get to 3?

Comment: nonono, not signal bandwidth, symbol rate. With a 2MSym/s symbol rate and a sampling rate of 4MHz, you get 2sps. But other than that, yes

Comment: (note that signal bandwidth is a function of symbol rate and the pulse shaping filter, that's why it's necessary to make a difference here)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well Bandwidth and Bit/rate are linked. If my zigbee shoot 2 MegaChip/s, it will result in using 2Mhz of frequency right?

Comment: Chip rate != symbol rate. yes, bandwidth and symbol rate are linked, by various means, but in this pure OPSK case, in terms of comvolving the pulse shaping filter with the symbols, as I said.

Comment: I am working on exactly same problem. As you said, you were able to solve this in MATLAB, can you share some more details about how you exactly did that? I have a Polyphase Clock sync block followed by costas loop in gnuRadio but it still gives a rotating constellation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phase recovery was finaly perform in Matlab. Because the signal we are studying (Zigbee) send a preamble before the communication start, we can compensate for the group delay and the channel's distortion with a anti-causal analysis of the expected signal and the received signal.

The GNU-Radio's blocks  weren't efficient at recovering O-QPSK's signal. However with fact that we don't real time treatment of the signal, Matlab was finaly most suitable way to resolve the O-QPSK demodulation of the Zigbee signal.